# Unable to save variable in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to save the `request.headers` but it keeps returning `[object Object]` on the txt file.

```
var http = require("http");
url = require("url");
fs = require("fs");

var events = require('events');
var even = new events.EventEmitter();

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
  var head = request.headers;


var append = function(data ){
fs.appendFile('message.txt', data, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');

});
}
var time = new Date();
console.log(head);
append(head + ": "+ time+ "\n");
}).listen(8888);
```

Comment: What other format would you like to use if you don't like the `[object Object]` serialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
append(JSON.stringify(head) + ": " + time + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

before save you can save object to json example.

```
fs.appendFile('message.txt', JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
});
```